# Irish visa refused three years ago. How to reapply?

Tags: visas, ireland, indonesian-citizens

My boyfriend got denied a visa for Ireland on the basis of:

```
F :- Finances shown have been deemed insufficient
F :- Finances:- evidence provided is deemed insufficient or incomplete - bank 
     statements do not cover a six month period immediately prior to the application
OB :- Obligations to return to home country not shown - e.g. no social, economic or 
      professional ties in home country shown
OC :- Observe the conditions of the visa - the visa sought is for a specific purpose and 
      duration:- the applicant has not satisfied the visa officer that such conditions 
      would be observed
```

This decision can be appealed within 2 months of the date of this letter. An appeal must be submitted in writing, fully addressing all the reasons for refusal.

He didn't appeal this. This was in 2014. He wants to come to Ireland.  Does he have to address this or can he reapply for an Irish visa?

Comment: He can reapply for a visa, but unless he addresses the issues above (e.g. provides good quality evidence that his finances are sufficient) then the result will be the same.

Comment: All of these refusal reasons indicate lack of evidence of finances, or lack of evidence of nonimmigrant intentions. If you are able to provide the evidence of these, then the visa would likely be approved.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly point out the time for appeals is long gone, so the next logical step is to apply for a fresh visa. Anyone can apply for an Irish visa at any time, however I presume your goal is to avoid a second refusal. In this case I suggest the following:

- Make sure that there is a substantial change of circumstances since the last application. E.g. does your boyfriend now have a stable job or a new home in his country of residence?
- Read up [our excellent explanation on why visas are refused](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e). It's focused on the UK, but the same principles generally apply to the visa system in all developed countries.
- When you submit your application prepare a cover letter explaining what's changed since the last application.
- If in doubt, contact an Irish solicitor specializing in immigration questions. That's the 'golden' solution to any problematic visa application, as it lets you avoid any pitfalls in the process.

Another solution would be for the two of you to get married - in this case a different set of rules would begin to apply and the whole application would become a lot easier.

Comment: Hi JonathanReez yes we do plan to marry next year when i visit bali.